# How to list most recently updated parent upper in the query?

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I have pic related parent/child tables. For every one row in the parent table, there can be like 100 or 200 child rows in the child table. When I upgrade the child table; I also give it's parent row's tID number to child's row under thread ID column. So, there isn't more than one parent row to each child row.

If I had a column in the parent table like "LastChildTimestamp" could I upgrade related row with the last child timestamp? If so can you show me an example?

What I want to achieve is to keep the most recently updated parents upper when I list out the parents and I want to make it easy. So if you have a better solution or method I'm open to it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different approaches you could use to solve this problem.

1. Create the parent.LastChildTimestamp field, then use a database trigger to update it.

See: http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_update.php

In particular, you would set up after insert and after update triggers in the child table that would update the associated parent row.

2. Alternately, you could instead simply aggregate the data from the child rows when you need to read it. Your query would looks something like:

SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP)
FROM child
WHERE child.threadID = (thread ID)

Comment: I ended up adding another column which gets updated whenever a new child row added with new child's auto increment value. This way I can order parents' list by this column DESC.